# OpenGL glTranslatef

Tags: opengl, rotation

I'm trying to rotate my 2D triangle around it's origin, but it's rotating inward, visibly shrinking in size then expanding.

Also I only ever seem to be able to rotate it vertically unless I'm using Cos and Sin but then triangle spirals out of control when it's supposed to rotate around the hexagon.

Here's a gif of the current outcome (I know, I didn't set the origin right, it's not a mistake, I was testing a different result). https://i.stack.imgur.com/XERZo.gif

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(Position.X, Position.Y, 0.0f);
            glRotatef(x_rotation * 360, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glRotatef(y_rotation * 360, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(-Position.X, -Position.Y + 0.125, 0.0f);

    //color
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    //geometrical shape
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f( 0.00f, -1.25f, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(-0.15f, -1.0f,  0.0);
        glVertex3f( 0.15f, -1.0f,  0.0);
    glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: The class object constructor defines it's position
`gObjects.push_back(new PlayerTriangle(Vector2D(0, -1)));`
My render functions looks like this
`// Reset transformations
glLoadIdentity();
// Set the camera
gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f,
   0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
   0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f);

for (unsigned i = 0; i < gObjects.size(); i++) {
  gObjects.at(i)->Update();
  gObjects.at(i)->Render(); 
}

 glutSwapBuffers();`

Comment: the 10.0f is the z position of the camera and the code in my OP is the first on the stack

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I fixed it.

```
    glTranslatef (Position.X, Position.Y,  0.0f);
    glTranslatef (-Position.X, -Position.Y,0.0f);
          glRotatef  (y_rotation * 360, 0.0f, 1.0f, 4.0f);
          glRotatef  (x_rotation * 360, 0.0f, 1.0f, 4.0f);
    glTranslatef (0.0f,       0.0f,       0.0f);`
```

Needed to change about x, y and z params on glRotatef.